# "Представить": индикатив или сослагательное наклонение?

Tags: наклонение

Стараюсь разобраться в выборе наклонения после глагола *представить*. Вот мои наблюдения: после него в придаточном предложении может использоваться индикатив и сослагательное наклонение + в главном предложении важно присутствие отрицания.

> Никто и представить себе не мог, **что** Россия **окажется** под санкциями.
>
> Никто и представить себе не мог, **чтобы** Россия **оказалась** под санкциями.

Индикатив стоит когда в придаточном предложении реальное действие описывается; сослагательное наклонение - когда речь про гипотетическиe ситуации.

Вроде всё выглядит структурированно и логично, но я находила примеры, в которых используется индикатив, хотя речь про ситуации, которые еще не имели место в реальном мире, например:

> Никто и представить себе не мог, **что может найтись** человек счастливее
>   меня.

(человек счастливее персонажа не был найден!)

Бросается в глаза то, что в некоторых примерах (с гипотетическими действиями) союз "чтобы" звучит *коряво*(?). Вы наверное ведь тоже эту версию этой версии "Никто и представить себе не мог, чтобы мог найтись человек счастливее меня" предпочли бы, нет?

Anyway у Вас есть какая-нибудь мысль, которая поможет понять мне от чего зависит выбор наклонения после этого глагола?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
Никто и представить себе не мог, что может найтись человек счастливее меня.
(человек счастливее персонажа не был найден!)
```

Но ведь вовсе не обязательно, что не найден, вполне можно сказать это же в ситуации, когда найден, потому все и удивились: его не должно быть, а он есть.

```
Никто и представить себе не мог, чтобы мог найтись человек счастливее меня
```

Предложение действительно некорректно, потому что там повтор:"не мог, чтобы мог " А если его устранить, будет всё в порядке:

Никто и представить себе не мог, **чтобы   нашёлся** человек счастливее меня.

На мой взгляд, выбор наклонения здесь произволен, подобные синтаксические единицы синонимичны.

Answer (score 1):

1)  Никто и представить себе не мог, **что** Россия **окажется** под санкциями.Никто и представить себе не мог, **чтобы** Россия **оказалась** под санкциями.

Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным. В главном предложении прошедшее время, поэтому содержание придаточного является для него будущим, которое пока неизвестно.  Такое содержание можно выразить с помощью ДВУХ синонимичных  форм: будущего времени в изъявительном наклонении (союз ЧТО) или  формы сослагательного наклонения со значением предположения (союз ЧТОБЫ + глагол с суффиксом Л).

Примечание. Кстати, будущее здесь НЕОДНОЗНАЧНО, например:  Никто и представить себе не мог, что Россия окажется под санкциями, **но** она оказалась. Никто и представить себе не мог, что Россия окажется под санкциями, **и** она не оказалась.

3) Другой пример (две те же синонимичные формы): Никто и представить себе не мог, **что** Россия **проиграет** войну, и она ее не проиграла. Никто и представить себе не мог, **чтобы** Россия **проиграла** войну, и она ее не проиграла.

4) Никто и представить себе не мог, что может найтись человек счастливее меня.

С точки зрения грамматики,  человек может найтись или не найтись, но смысл предложения не в этом. Смысл в том, что герой был настолько счастлив, что, кажется, счастливее быть нельзя, но  потом всё могло измениться.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, Arina! Скажите я правильно поняла: получается что выбор наклонения зависит от говорящего? от того, как он сам расценивает ситуацию?

Comment: Я думаю, что обе формы (изъявит. и сослагат. наклонение)  здесь синонимичны, но смысл этого выражения может меняться в зависимости от ситуации.  Оно обычно используется для оценки МАЛОВЕРОЯТНОГО (с точки зрения говорящего) события, которое  не происходит (что ожидаемо) или происходит (что удивительно). Вот, например: Никто (из россиян) и представить себе не мог, что Россия проиграет войну, и она ее не проиграла. Никто (из врагов) и представить себе не мог, что Россия выиграет войну, а она ее выиграла. Событие уже известно, а предварительные оценки у говорящих были разные.